# How to handle duplicate node names when converting xml to csv using java and xsl

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

I am given an xml file from an outside source (so I have no control over the attribute names) and unfortunately they use the same name for a paired set of data. I can't seem to figure out how to access the second value. An example of the data in the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<addressResponse>
  <results>
      <ownerName>Name1</ownerName>
      <houseAddress>House1</houseAddress>
      <houseAddress>CityState1</houseAddress>
      <yearBuilt>Year1</yearBuilt>
  </results>
  <results>
      <ownerName>Name2</ownerName>
      <houseAddress>House2</houseAddress>
      <houseAddress>CityState2</houseAddress>
      <yearBuilt>Year2</yearBuilt>
  </results>
</addressResponse>
```

I already have my java code together and can parse the xml but I need help handling the duplicate attribute name. I want my csv file to look like the following:

```
owner,address,citystate,yearbuilt
Name1,House1,CityState1,Year1
Name2,House2,CityState2,Year2
```

In my xsl file, I did the following "hoping" it would get the second houseAddress but it didn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">owner,address,citystate,yearbuilt
<xsl:for-each select="//results>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ownerName,',',houseAddress,',',houseAddress,',',yearBuilt,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That gave me:

```
owner,address,citystate,yearbuilt
Name1,House1,House1,Year1
Name2,House2,House2,Year2
```

Is there a trick to do this? I can't get the attribute names changed from the originator so I'm stuck with them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's invalid XSLT code and it does NOT produce the claimed result.

Comment: I typed it in by hand so I may have made a mistake. I'll Double check

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did have typos, apoligies

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
houseAddress[2]
```

to get the value of the second occurrence of the `houseAddress` element.

*Note that we are assuming XSLT 1.0 here.*

Comment: OMG, it was that simple? I'm sorry to have wasted your time. I searched for an answer but didn't see anything like this. Thank you for the solution.